# Why is Get-AzPolictState -PolicyAssignmentName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" returning no response?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I've run variations of this command and I continue to get no response when using the policy assignment name.

```
Get-AzPolictState -PolicyAssignmentName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -Filter "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute'"
```

Link to site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-9.0.1

Comment: When was the policy assigned? It takes a few times for the first state to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

i have reproduced in my environment, and got expected results as below and followed below process and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-9.1.0):

Firstly, I have tried your command as below:

```
Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "XX" -Filter "ResourceType eq 'microsoft.compute'"
```

[image]

And I didn't get any response as below:

To be sure i have also tried with `Microsoft.KeyVault` :

[image]

I haven't got any response.

So, when I used below command, I got expected results:

```
Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "XX" -Filter "ResourceType eq 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'"
```

Output:
[image]

```
Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "XX"ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults'"
```

Output:

[image]

So, what I learnt is you need to use full Resource Type not half name or some part of it to get output.
Try to follow above process, you will get output as i have got.

If you have created new policy, you need to wait for some time then it will show you the output.